# Как присвоить данные переменной, которые вводит человек боту в телеграмме

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

***Как работает бот***: бот спрашивает название города, человек пишет, и дальше идёт код с этим названием

Comment: можно увидеть вашу попытку решить эту задачу?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что Вы сделали, чтобы решить данную задачу. И да, если уж не удосужились прочитать приветственную справку от ruSO, почитайте хоть это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите город: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    print('введённый пользователем город:', message.text)
```

[Пример на странице библиотеки](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)